# How to improve project Euler 580 solution

Tags: python

This is the question text:

> A Hilbert number is any positive integer of the form 4k+14k+1 for integer k≥0k≥0. We shall define a squarefree Hilbert number as a Hilbert number which is not divisible by the square of any Hilbert number other than one. For example, 117117 is a squarefree Hilbert number, equaling 9×139×13. However 62376237 is a Hilbert number that is not squarefree in this sense, as it is divisible by 9292. The number 39693969 is also not squarefree, as it is divisible by both 9292 and 212212.
>
> There are 23271922327192 squarefree Hilbert numbers below 107107.
> How many squarefree Hilbert numbers are there below 10161016?

Below is my code. How can I make this faster?

```
from math import sqrt

def if_squarefree(x):

i = 1
maybe = 0

while maybe < int(sqrt(x)) + 1 :

    tmp = 4 * i + 1

    maybe = tmp * tmp

    if x % maybe == 0 :
        return False
    i = i + 1

return True

def find_squarefree() :

end = pow(10,16)
i = pow(10,7)
cnt = 0

while i < end :
    print i
    tmp = 4 * i + 1
    if if_squarefree(tmp) :
        cnt = cnt + 1
    i = i + 1
return cnt


find_squarefree()
```

thank you :)

Comment: If your code is working and you want to optimize it you should try the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about it wrong. Try running this program:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.utcnow()
i = 0

while True:
    i += 1
    if i % 10**7 == 0:
        print(i)
        print((datetime.utcnow() - start ).total_seconds())
```

Note how long it takes to count up to `10**7` aka `pow(10,7)`. Now imagine what it takes to count up to pow(10,16).
And this is just the counting in your `while i < end` loop - This is excluding the loop in the call to `if_squrefree()`

On my box. counting from 1 -> 1000000 takes 1.4 seconds. So by math
counting from 1 -> 100000000000000 will take ~ 45 years. Hence this approach won't work.